Minimum spanning tree variation for node-weighted graph
I'm trying to solve a variation of the minimum spanning tree problem; I have a graph where there are certain key nodes and optional nodes. Each optional node has a weight and we need to find a subset of the nodes which spans all the key nodes while minimizing the total weight of the optional nodes. Since the key nodes are mandatory they don't have weights. The edges also don't have weights, they are in sense free as soon as both nodes it connects are selected. I made an example with the key nodes marked in red and the solution (I think) in green.

Edit:
While I thought this might reduce to an MST I'm thinking it might actually be a steiner tree problem and therefore NP-hard. The use-case is for a video game, so a fast (and simple) approximate solution is much preferred.

If you had the distances between each pair of mandatory nodes, you'd be able to use those to find the MST...

@beaker this doesn't work I think you can make counter examples

Ah, yes, you'd need the shortest paths between all nodes so that if an optional node ends up in the MST, you don't accidentally take a longer path to the next mandatory node.

A standard greedy algorithm will give you a reasonable first solution.  Like so: Find minimum spanning tree of all nodes with every node weight 1.  Iterate over optional nodes in order of decreasing weight, check if it can be skipped.  In your example, first try node with weight 70 and find it can be removed.  Continue with reduced graph.  When you reach the node with weight 20, you will find it cannot be removed because you lose connection with the red node at the top of the figure.

A more sophisticated approach:   Iterate over optional nodes in order of decreasing weight.  If the code can be removed without splitting the graph into two ( or more ) components, remove it.  When iteration complete find MST of remaining graph.

Neither algorithm will guarantee the optimum solution but they are fast and simple approximations that can be easily implemented if you have a feature rich graph theory library.

@WARdd Can you explain why you don't think the Shortest-Paths/MST approach will work?

@beaker imagine a wheel-spoke shaped graph where the central node is optional and has weight 2. The wheel is made of alternating key nodes and optional nodes of weight 1. If you make a shortest-path graph between keys you would get a wheel with edges of weight 1 and a web of spokes in the middle with weight 2 each. a MST will just cover the wheel and avoid the web of spokes, because it doesn't understand the spokes are all one and the same node. The actual solution ofc. is to just pay 2 and connect all the keys at once.

For your wheel spoke graph, the algorithms I suggest would not remove the hub, because it would split the graph into many components, but it would then remove all the optional nodes, giving you your optimal solution.

This is a special case of the maximum-weight connected subgraph problem. It's NP-hard, but can in practice be solved efficiently even for graphs with tens of thousands of nodes. Best software to solve it: https://scipjack.zib.de/ (disclaimer, I'm one of the developers)

Why do you disclaim your own software?

was meant in the sense of "warning"

Hmm, ok, then I guess it's somewhat appropriate, though still odd. (I had suspected you meant "disclosure", as that's what saying "I'm one of the developers" is, but that has nothing to do with warning.)
